# Plotting of NSolve solutions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am sorry for such an easy question, but I am still not very good at *Mathematica*. I would like to plot the solution of

```
NSolve[(-p^2 v1^2 + (E1 - Ce) (E1 + gam1 - Ce)) (E1^2 - 
     p^2 v1^2 + Ce (gam1 + Ce) - 
     E1 (gam1 + 2 Ce)) == 
  0, E, {p, -10^-7, 10^-7, 0.0000001}]
```

on one figure. I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: `NSolve` is a numerical procedure and needs numerical input, i.e. you need to give values to the parameteres `p`, `v1` etc. And I guess you meant the lonely `E` to be `E1` - `E` is a built-in symbol being the basis of the natural logarithm $e\approx 2.72$. Also, how do you want to plot a solutions of an algebraic equation? It's not a function but a list of values `E1` satisfying the eq. Like $x=\pm 1$ are solutions to `x^2-1==0`.

Comment: Your question is badly formulated. You have an equation that looks like an algebraic. However, you use a syntax that partially applies to algebraic, and partially - to differential equations. Second, you have a number of parameters. To plot the solution you have to fix most of them. Third, `E` is reserved in Mma for the exponential. I suggest that you might edit your question making clear all these points.

Comment: OK, I am sorry I didn't provide full data the question is how to plot {{{E -> -0.413317}, {E-> 
-0.0233172}, {E -> 0.0233172}, {E -> 
    0.413317}}, {{E-> -0.39}, {E -> 
    0.}, {E-> 0.}, {E -> 
    0.39}}, {{E-> -0.413317}, {E -> \
-0.0233172}, {E -> 0.0233172}, {E -> 
    0.413317}}} as a function  of {p, -10^-7, 10^-7, 0.0000001}

Comment: How did you get that output? Please provide a full code; and see my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is the output taking into the consideration all of data i do have. I know that this is a list of the value, the question  is how to plot an list of the solutions as a function of some variable? I would be grateful for n answer

Comment: From what I know about ListPlot is that one needs a for of {x_1,y_1} in the list, so I do not know what to do list of the form {{x_1,x'_1,x''_1,...},{x_2,x'_2,x''_2,...},...,{x_n,x_n',x''_n,...}

Comment: Again: show the code that lead you to those values (those are values of `E`, which, **as was said before**, is a built-in symbol and hence has one, unchangeable value of $\approx 2.72$). The code in your OP is highly erroneous, as pointed out by me and Alexei, and gives no output. Your result is irreproducible as it stands now. What are the values of the constants `p`, `Ce`, `gam1`? Provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

To `Solve` the algebraic equation for `E1`:

```
sol = Solve[(-p^2 v1^2 + (E1 - Ce) (E1 + gam1 - Ce)) (E1^2 - 
      p^2 v1^2 + Ce (gam1 + Ce) - E1 (gam1 + 2 Ce)) == 0, E1]
```

[image]

Substitute given values of `p`:

```
sol2 = Table[sol /. p -> i, {i, -10^-7, 10^-7, 10^-7}]
```

[image]

Give numerical values to the parameters:

```
y = E1 /. sol2 /. {Ce -> 1, gam1 -> 1, v1 -> 1} // N // Chop
```

> {{0, 1., 1., 2.}, {0, 1., 1., 2.}, {0, 1., 1., 2.}}

```
x = N@Table[i, {i, -10^-7, 10^-7, 10^-7}]
```

> {-1.*10^-7, 0., 1.*10^-7}

Plot the pairs of points:

```
ListPlot[#, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}] &@
   Flatten[#, 1] &@Diagonal@Outer[List, x, y, 1, 2]
    (* or *)
ListPlot[#, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}] &@
   Flatten[#, 2] &@MapThread[Outer[List, {#1}, #2] &, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear corey979 thank you for answer it is very helpful

Comment: @ArthurAltman Glad it helped. If you find it useful, you might want to consider accepting/upvoting it.